# bootstrap modal ajax petition

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to show the data into the dialog but this does not work, the modal show the data as written in the html...any help?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#billDetail').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
    var billId = button.data('whatever');

    var url = "/admin/bills/find";            
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            data: {
                "billId" : billId
                }, // Adjuntar los campos del formulario enviado.
            success: function(data)
            {   
                var modal = $(this)
                modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + data)
                modal.find('.modal-body input').val(data)
                modal.show();
           }

      });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `.html` not `.text`

```
modal.find('.modal-title').html('New message to ' + data);
```

Hope this will help you.